# Detecting Static Footage in FCP

Tags: macos, screen-capture, final-cut-pro, motion

I'd like to strip out all footage in screen captures where there is no onscreen motion or changes. These are screen captures of non-motion video sources like leaderboards in a game.

I would think there are two ways to do this: one would be to get my Mac to act like a security cam with a motion-detector, and only record when there are screen changes.

The other way, which I'll probably have to resort to if I can, is to detect when frames change, and introduce cuts. But I can't find a way to do either. I use Final Cut Pro, and DaVinci.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is one of those tasks you could do manually in little more time than it takes to watch it. Watch until still frame, cut, drag backwards til end of still, drop back into play. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: There was an algorithm written to do this years ago - used to remove adverts from films shown on TV's when recorded onto vcr... iirc it worked by looking at the color range and how the audio was single voice cf several characters etc

Comment: @Tetsujin but I'm talking about potentially 96+ hours of video here. The source will probably be my Twitch streams, where people are logging in to play a game and register points on a board. Twitch will handle the video recording, and I can probably manually segment it every twenty-four hours, although this adds another task in a process that needs to be automated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PySceneDetect

There is a Python application (command line) called [PySceneDetect](https://pyscenedetect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which should be able to help:

> PySceneDetect is a command-line application and a Python library for detecting shot changes in videos (example), and automatically splitting the video into separate clips. Not only is it free and open-source software (FOSS), but there are several detection methods available (see Features), from simple threshold-based fade in/out detection, to advanced content aware fast-cut detection of each shot.

Also see [Is there a video change detection software available?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57524590/4778030)